# Add clarifying text to the tags section of the profile

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

I'm confused by the tag sections in my profile, and I'm wondering if others might be as well. I noticed that my top tag was listed under my reputation:

[image: My top tag]

So I clicked on the "tags" section to see which tags I had answered questions for. There, I see a different set of numbers by the same tag:

[image: Tags I've answered questions in]

So what do the various numbers mean? I assume +90 means I've gotten 90 reputation points (overall or just recently?) in that tag. But what are the 42 and x13 in the lower section? The number of questions/answers I've posted in that tag? Something else?

I'm guessing I'm not the only one confused by this. Perhaps some clarifying text somewhere in the UI would make this more obvious?

Comment: This belongs on the Stack Exchange Meta; you'll be able to reach a wider audience there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each number has an explanatory tooltip.

[image: 478 [vba] x 123: Asked 29 non-wiki questions with a total score of 272. Gave 93 non-wiki answers with a total score of 478]

So, that 42 is your net score for the [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag (which counts toward your tag badge), and the x13 is the number of posts you have in that tag (questions & answers combined).

Tag score is the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes under a given tag. Because only non-wiki answer upvotes count toward a tag badge, that's what the numbers are showing.

[More information on tag badges here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/197901)

Answer (score 5):

Hovering over the text tells you the score and number of your non-wiki questions and answers, and possibly your wiki questions and answers.  The number to the left is the score of your non-wiki answers in that tag, and the number to the left is the total number of posts with that tag.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the info! Rollovers don't work on tablets, do they? I'm not a big fan of them because they're not very discoverable even when you can do them.

Comment: No, hover tips don't work well on tablets, and no, they aren't easily discoverable unless you hover over everything just to see if it has one.